# Assigning a value to id doesn't stick

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading a plist from a file and want to set a number of properties to the values from the file, but only if they're not nil, so I came up with a little method, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
- (void)assignNonNullValue:(id)value to:(id)target
{
    if (value) {
        target = value;
        NSLog(@"new value = %@", target);
    }
}

// ...

    NSString *foo = @"a";
    [self assignNonNullValue:@"b" to:foo];
    NSLog(@"foo=%@", foo);
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
new value = b
foo=b
```

but instead I got:

```
new value = b
foo=a
```

Why?

Comment: First you should probably use a `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing target value  in your method. It won't affect value of foo in another scope. It want to change `foo` value, you need to pass your method where it points to. So that, when you change in a method, it'll affect `foo` value as you're changing the value it points to. To clarify my explanation, here is the code

```
- (void)assignNonNullValue:(id)value to:(id *)target
{
    if(value != nil)
        *target = value;
}
```

It's really really rare that you use `id *` as `id` is a already pointer to an object.  .Passing  `id *` as a parameter allows you to change the value where it points to. So that, it's going to be permanent.

After you've made the changes i pointed. You need to call this method as

```
[self assignNonNullValue:@"b" to:&foo];
```

Comment: Your code does work for a local variable, but not for a property: _"Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back"_.

Comment: if you're using property, you can access assign a value to your property using self, why would you bother using a method.

Comment: You should point out that this solution requires a change to how the method is called. `[self assignNonNullValue:@"b" to:&foo];`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
- (id)valueOrOriginalIfNull:(id)value original:(id)original {
    if (value) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return original;
    }
}

// ...

NSString *foo = @"a";
foo = [self valueOrOriginalIfNull:@"b" original:foo];
NSLog(@"foo=%@", foo);
```

The reason your original approach fails is that parameters are passed by value. When you assign `target` to another value inside the method, it has no affect on the original value.